# Supervisord get confused two programs in configuration file

Tags: php, queue, laravel-5.1, supervisord, beanstalkd

I have two `laravel 5.1` aplications that uses `beanstalkd` and `supervisord` to manage queue jobs.

The supervisord.conf file has the two programs defined as

```
[program:diagbovespa-default-queue]
command=php artisan queue:listen --tries=2 --env=aceite
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
directory=/sciere/sites/diagbovespa.aceite.pro.br
numprocs=2
user=apache
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/sciere/sites/diagbovespa.aceite.pro.br/storage/logs/queue_supervisord.log

[program:questionarioise-default-queue]
command=php artisan queue:listen --tries=2 --env=aceite
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
directory=/sciere/sites/questionarioise.aceite.pro.br
numprocs=2
user=apache
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/sciere/sites/questionarioise.aceite.pro.br/storage/logs/queue_supervisord.log
```

The `queue.php` file for `diagbovespa` application has `beanstalkd` defined as

```
    'beanstalkd' => [
        'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
        'host'   => 'localhost',
        'queue'  => 'default',
        'ttr'    => 60,
    ],
```

and the `queue.php` `questionarioise` application has `beanstalkd` defined as

```
    'beanstalkd' => [
        'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
        'host'   => 'localhost',
        'queue'  => 'questionarioise',
        'ttr'    => 60,
    ],
```

So beanstalkd consider two queue groups, `default` and `questionarioise`.

The problem is that when I send an email via laravel default queue (program:diagbovespa-default-queue), sometimes I receive email from `diagbovespa`, sometiems from `questionarioise`.

What I'm missing in `supervisord` and/or `beanstalkd` configuration?

Comment: You can't have two config arrays with an array key of `beanstalkd`, they have to be uniquely named.

Comment: Thanks @jszobody, I updated the question. There are two separate `queue.php` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queue workers don't have a queue name specified, so they'll pick up any jobs with any queue label.

In your configs you have `'queue'  => 'default'` and `'queue'  => 'questionarioise'`. You need to update your queue workers to listen and handle those jobs only:

```
[program:diagbovespa-default-queue]
command=php artisan queue:listen --tries=2 --env=aceite --queue=default
```

And:

```
[program:questionarioise-default-queue]
command=php artisan queue:listen --tries=2 --env=aceite --queue= questionarioise
```

Though I'd suggest changing the first queue name from `default` to something more specific like `diagbovespa`, and use that in supervisord as well.